# How come I don't can't print out error from my throw exception?

Tags: c++, exception

I am just learning throw exception and I wrote a code but it doesn't seem like I can print out `Error: too big` or `Error:too large` when I entered `10000` or `100000`. How can I fix it so that it can print out `Error: too big` or `Error:too large`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdexcept>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int xxx;
    cout<<"please enter xxx:";
    cin>>xxx;
    if (xxx==1)
       cout<<"2";
    else if (xxx==10)
       cout<<"3";
    else if (xxx==100)
       cout<<"4";
    else if (xxx==1000)
       cout<<"5";
    else if (xxx==10000)
       throw "too big";
    else if (xxx==100000)
       throw "too large";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You add a `try{} catch(const char* msg)  { cout << msg << endl; }`

Answer (score 5):

You seem to attribute too much magic to exceptions.

But at the core of it, exceptions are really simple. Basically, it just means that some low-level code creates an object (via `throw`) that ends up in some higher-level code (via `catch`).

When there is no `catch`, then the exception keeps "falling down" the function-call stack, and it keeps doing so until it "falls off" `main`.

When this happens, a series of special events takes place. You can configure the behaviour with relatively advanced techniques, but all a beginner really needs to know is that you are **not guaranteed any error message being printed** in this case. If you want an exception to result in an error message, then you have to write the necessary code yourself.

Adapting your original example, that code may look like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdexcept>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        int xxx;
        cout<<"please enter xxx:";
        cin>>xxx;
        if (xxx==1)
           cout<<"2";
        else if (xxx==10)
           cout<<"3";
        else if (xxx==100)
           cout<<"4";
        else if (xxx==1000)
           cout<<"5";
        else if (xxx==10000)
           throw "too big";
        else if (xxx==100000)
           throw "too large";
        return 0;
    }
    catch (char const* exc)
    {
        cerr << exc << "\n";
    }
}
```

However, what adds to the confusion here is that unlike most other languages with exceptions, C++ allows you to **throw objects any type**.

Let's take a closer look at this line here:

> ```
> throw "too big";
> ```

`"too big"` is a literal of type `char const[8]`. C++ allows you to throw such an object. And since it can be converted to a `char const*` to its first element, you can even catch it and string literals of other sizes as `char const*`.

But that's **not common practice**. You should instead throw objects derived directly or indirectly from `std::exception`.

Here is an example using the standard class [`std::runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) from the `<stdexcept>` header.

<sup>*(Your original code did not use anything from `<stdexcept>`. You can perfectly use `throw` itself without `<stdexcept>`.)*</sup>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <exception>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        int xxx;
        std::cout << "please enter xxx:";
        std::cin >> xxx;
        if (xxx==1)
           std::cout << "2";
        else if (xxx==10)
           std::cout << "3";
        else if (xxx==100)
           std::cout << "4";
        else if (xxx==1000)
           std::cout << "5";
        else if (xxx==10000)
           throw std::runtime_error("too big");
        else if (xxx == 100000)
           throw std::runtime_error("too large");
        return 0;
    }
    catch (std::exception const& exc)
    {
        std::cerr << exc.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

throw must e written in the try block only so write all the conditions in the try block and perform operations by catching them outside the try block immediately

```
    try
{
condition
throw exception ;
}
catch exception
{
message or correction lines 
}
```

---

Comment: Throws must be written in try blocks, but those blocks can be arbitrarily far down the call stack and do not have to be local at all.