# Cannot print message from exception

Tags: c++, exception

I am trying to throw an exception after catching one following [How come I don't can't print out error from my throw exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593442/how-come-i-dont-cant-print-out-error-from-my-throw-exception) but it does not print the message. It just prints `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'` instead of `test`

Here is the short snippet

```
try{
        if(A.size().lines != B.size().lines || A.size().cols != B.size().lines){
            throw std::runtime_error("test");
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception const& exc)
    {
        std::cerr << exc.what() << "\n";
    }
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You are throwing a `const char *` (meaning you wrote something like `throw "error";`) and never catch it. Use a debugger which will stop the program when the uncaught exception is thrown, so you don't need to find it manually.

Comment: Curious. Are you sure you're not compiling a previous version of your file ?

Comment: You can print messages from within `catch` blocks. Your code is completely fine. That means that the code you posted is not responsible for your problem.

Comment: @Quentin argh you are right. I just wasnt compiling the right file. Thank you